# How to count different values in one column of table in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a situation where i have to count number of strings of same type in one column of a table, for eg. a column would be having values such as :-

apple, apple, apple, orange,orange, banana, banana, banana, banana

So i need to count all the strings of same type, that means query should give count result 3 for apples, 2 for oranges and 4 for banana.

What can be idol query for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT column_name, count(*) 
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY column_name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use GROUP BY -

```
select columnName, count(*) from tableName
group by columnName
```

This will give you the results of how many apples, orange, banana are there in that column

Answer (score 0):

My need was count of same column with different values

```
SELECT durum_id, count(*)   FROM kontrol WHERE tarih='2017 2 28' and tur_id=2 GROUP BY durum_id
```

[image]